# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running an app from a terminal has no effect

Tags: 11.10, shared-library

I have several builds of an application on my system (a dev build and many older released builds). When I'm trying to run an older release, the system invariably picks up the dynamic libraries from the dev build.

From `/home/franz/Projects/appleseed/archives/releases/1.1.0-alpha-14-0-g4e46ed9/appleseed/bin` which is the directory of the older release I'm trying to run:

```
$ ldd appleseed.studio 
    [stuff omitted]
libappleseed.so => /home/franz/Projects/appleseed/build/linux-gcc4/appleseed/libappleseed.so (0x00007fbcb090b000)
libappleseed.shared.so => /home/franz/Projects/appleseed/build/linux-gcc4/appleseed.shared/libappleseed.shared.so (0x00007fbcb030c000)
    [more stuff omitted]
```

(`/home/franz/Projects/appleseed/build/linux-gcc4/appleseed/` is the path to my dev build.)

Naturally I should set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly before running an older release:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/franz/Projects/appleseed/archives/releases/1.1.0-alpha-14-0-g4e46ed9/appleseed/bin ; ./appleseed.studio
```

(`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is initially empty so I don't bother with concatenation.)

However this doesn't work and the system continues to pick up the dev build of the dynamic libraries.

Am I doing something wrong? Any idea?

I am running a 64-bit build of Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat (unsupported as of April 2012).

UPDATE: I have updated my system to Ubuntu 11.10 (Natty) and the problem persists.

Comment: What does `file .../libappleseed.so` output? Maybe you are trying to use an old 32-bit library with your new 64-bt binary.

Comment: Everything is 64-bit: `$ file ./libappleseed.so` returns `./libappleseed.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`, while `$ file /home/franz/Projects/appleseed/build/linux-gcc4/appleseed/libappleseed.so` returns `/home/franz/Projects/appleseed/build/linux-gcc4/appleseed/libappleseed.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`.

Comment: Ok, then you might want to check whether `ldd` still reports the other paths with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/franz/Projects/appleseed/archives/releases/1.1.0-alpha-14-0-g4e46ed9/appleseed/bin ldd ./appleseed.studio`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/franz/Projects/appleseed/archives/releases/1.1.0-alpha-14‌​-0-g4e46ed9/appleseed/bin ldd ./appleseed.studio` returns `libappleseed.so => /home/franz/Projects/appleseed/build/linux-gcc4/appleseed/libappleseed.so (0x00007fc27cce5000)`. I am at loss here. It looks like the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` mechanism is somehow disabled on my system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that under

   ```
   /home/franz/Projects/appleseed/archives/releases/1.1.0-alpha-14-0-g4e46ed9/appleseed/bin
   ```

   you really have the shared libraries you want to load. Are they really in the `bin/` directory of the archive? Not `lib/`?
2. Try

   ```
   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path /home/franz/Projects/appleseed/archives/releases/1.1.0-alpha-14-0-g4e46ed9/appleseed/bin ./appleseed.studio
   ```

   You can use the options from that program to control and debug the library loading process.

Comment: Absolutely, the `bin/` directory does contain the shared libraries I want to load. Is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` supposed to be an executable binary? I haven't got it in my system.

Comment: OK, it seems to be Linux's dynamic linker: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html. Seems like I should be able to install it via the package manager.

Comment: Can't seem to find `ld-linux-so.2`, `ld-linux.so` or `ld.so` in the package list or via `apt-get`.

Comment: The dynamic linker seems to be called `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on my system. So if I run the command you suggested, appleseed.studio starts but immediately complains that it isn't started from the `bin/` directory of its installation.

Comment: Here's what appleseed.studio says: "The application failed to start because it is not properly installed. Please reinstall the application. Specifically, it was expected that ld-2.12.1.so would reside in a bin/ subdirectory inside the main directory of the application, but it appears not to be the case (ld-2.12.1.so seems to be located in /lib)."

Comment: Hm, I can't help you any more, I'm at loss.

Comment: You might want to read [this discussion](http://appleseedhq.net/node/306), your error message is explicitly mentioned there.

Comment: Alright, no problem. Thanks a lot for you help. Seems like there may be a problem with how this version of Ubuntu handles `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the link. I am actually the author of appleseed :)

Comment: lol, my bad. Good luck anyways!

Answer (score 0):

For 64 bit, /usr/bin/ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld is the loader, not the 32 bit /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so.   No 32 bit loader is needed for this.

The ldd command indicates that the shared libraries it uses are in .../appleseed and .../appleseed.shared. Adding a new place for the needed libraries (the .../bin) will not change this, nor pick up the libraries in .../bin.  The question that remains is how the ldd is picking up these libraries if they are not in a standard location nor in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I would check on how the executable was linked, you could have given a full path on the necessary libraries, and not rely on just a name, needing a set of places to scan which LD_LIBRARY_PATH would provide.